# Easy Digital Download Pagination 404 error - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, easy-digital-downloads

Im facing issues with wordpress digital download website for pagination on homepage.

**Below pages doesn't seem to work with pagination when I go navigate through pagination, it shows 404 page.**

[www.domain.com/page/2/][1] 
[www.domain.com/page/3/][1]

**But when I edit the links e.g below it works:**

[www.domain.com/downloads/page/2/][1] 
[www.domain.com/downloads/page/3/][1]

Why it is happening, **same homepage code works fine with archives/categories/tags but not for homepage**, I have been searching for this from yesterday and I couldn't find any solution:
Below My code for homepage
**Your help is much appreciated**

```
<?php
$store_page_setting = (is_front_page() && is_page_template('edd-store-front.php') ? 'page' : 'paged' );
$current_page = get_query_var( $store_page_setting );
$per_page = intval( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_store_front_count', 3 ) );
$offset = $current_page > 0 ? $per_page * ( $current_page-1 ) : 0;
$product_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'download',
    'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
    'offset'        => $offset
);
$products = new WP_Query( $product_args );


if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php 
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); 
        // <!-- html code -->

endwhile;
?>

<!-- Pagination -->                 
<div class="store-pagination">
    <?php                   
        $big = 999999999;                   
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, $current_page ),
            'total' => $products->max_num_pages
        ) );
    ?>
</div>


<?php else : ?>

<article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
<!-- something -->
</article>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you need help with? `www.domain.com/downloads/page/2/` is correct, because WP needs to know what posts you are using pagination for.

Comment: @FluffyKitten On homepage I have pagination for my custom query, showing my EDD products. Clicking on pagination takes me to www.domain.com/page/2/ which shows 404, where in it should take to www.domain.com/downloads/page/2/ this.

Comment: In your `WP_Query` args you use `'post_type'  => 'download'`, but you say the working link used `downloads`, so should the post type not be `downloads` (i.e. with an s)?

Comment: sorry my bad its download only www.domain.com/download/page/2/

Comment: Ok, its not that then :) I see you are using `is_front_page`...is this on your homepage? Maybe its not adding the "download" folder to the url because its not included in the homepage url - if you change your Front Page in the admin, does it work then?